# Why when i try to run a project with hibernate4 it gives me the error: nested transaction not supported?

Tags: hql, hibernate-4.x

I upgraded hibernate in a project from version 3 to 4
I'm trying to select something from the database :

```
Configuration config;
        SessionFactory sf;
        ServiceRegistry sr;
        private static Manager m;

        private Manager() {
            config = new Configuration();
            config.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
            config.addAnnotatedClass(Produs.class);
            config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            sr = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties())
                    .buildServiceRegistry();
             new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);
            sf = config.buildSessionFactory(sr);
        }

    public void getProducts(){


    Session s = sf.getCurrentSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
            Query q=s.createQuery("from Produs as p WHERE p.numeProdus LIKE :numeP AND p.descriere LIKE :descriereP AND p.categorie LIKE :categorieP");
             q.setParameter("numeP", "%"+produs.getNumeProdus()+"%");
             q.setParameter("descriereP", "%"+produs.getDescriere()+"%");
             q.setParameter("categorieP", "%"+produs.getCategorie()+"%");           
             List l=q.list();
             return l;
    }
```

I did the same thing from the function "getProducts" in hibernate 3 and this works. In version 4 doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Between 3 and 4 there have been some changes. This is what I had to do after I upgraded from 3 to 4 to get things working.

```
    if (session.getTransaction() != null
            && session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        txD = session.getTransaction();
    } else {
        txD = session.beginTransaction();
    }

    //txD = session.beginTransaction();
    // txD.begin() ;
    session.saveOrUpdate(dataStore);
    try {
        txD.commit();
        while (!txD.wasCommitted())
            ;
    }
```